# I want to install 12.04LTS 64bit on HP Z820. Will there be any problems?

Tags: 12.04, installation, hardware, hp

I am considering the purchase of HP Z820.
I want to install 12.04LTS 64bit.
Z800 is given in the hardware support information.
Z820 is not written yet.
Please tell me if you know how it can be used in Z820.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [Specs](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/workstations/z820_features.html#.UXSrtnBDs94) I can see the following:

- Out of the several operating systems it can work on, Red Hat is one of them. Since a Linux OS is found there, you have a very good chance of having full support on Ubuntu.
- All the (Intel Xeon) Available Processors for it are supported in Ubuntu
- All Expansion Slots & Ports (USB, Sound...) are supported
- All Network, Sound & Storage Devices are supported.

The ones that would need further research would be:

- Drive Controllers - The controllers appear certified in the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/make/Intel%20Corporation/?page=5)
- Intel C602 Chipset - The chipset appears certified in the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/make/Intel%20Corporation/?page=5)
- Nvidia Graphics - This can be solved quickly by following the steps provided in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card/61433#61433)

But even after all of this, I want to add some additional info:

In the Ubuntu Forums, [a user tested out the HP Z820](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2096861) I concluded that everything worked ok.

A [Launchpad Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1028513) confirms a problem with the CPU when stressed. The issues looks like only affects 12.04 but a fix was released for 12.10+